# How to listen the on click and change the language instantly using list preference

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

**This is my code** :

```
public class SettingsPage extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.notification_setting)
RelativeLayout notification_setting;
@BindView(R.id.setting_back_image)
ImageView setting_back_image;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setting_back_image.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());

    notification_setting.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent settingsIntent = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName())
                    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, 1);
        }
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    });
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working in above code?

Comment: i have to change language instantly onClick of list preference option

Comment: in list preference fragment layout i have two option English and Hindi, on click of any one i get shared preference key, but iam unable to set language instantly.